# sizeof error while trying to find the size of an array

Tags: c, arrays

I have made this code for a homework problem but I get warning and I don't understand why. And when I open the program it doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int binarytodec(int array[]) {

  int i, result=0, n = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);

  for( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {

    if(array[i]==1) {
      result +=pow(2,i);
    } else if(array[i]==0) {
      result +=0;
    }
    else break;
  }
    return result;
}

int main() {

  int b[] = {1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,12};

  binarytodec(b);

  return 0;
}
```

The warning is:

> warning: sizeof on array function parameter will return size of
>         'int *' instead of 'int []' [-Wsizeof-array-argument]   int i, result=0, n = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);

What is the problem?

Thank you

Comment: @user3121023 that does not work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an array to a function in C, that array argument decays to a pointer and so the call to `sizeof` within the function you pass it to returns the size of the **pointer** itself, not the size in bytes of the array you pass.